# Is there a way to make the following code more generic?

Tags: java, java-8, gson, java-stream

I'm using gson to serialize/deserialize and java 8 stream. Following is the code snippet,

```
private long sumofTime() {
    Line[] lines = gson.fromJson(jsonString, Line[].class);
    return Arrays.stream(lines).filter(x -> x.hasTime())
                .mapToInt(x -> x.getTime).sum();
}
```

Line class looks like,

```
public class Line {
    String name;
    String stamp;
    Integer time;
    Integer xx;
    Integer yy;
    Integer zz;
    ...
    ...

    boolean hasTotalTime() {
        return totalTime != null;
    }
    ...
    getters...setters...}
```

Stream is used to check if specific variable(eg.time in the above example) is not null for each array element (i.e., Line), and then get the sum of all times.

Question: There are like 30 variables in the Line objects whose sum are needed, so how to make the solution more generic, instead of writing a sum method for each variable. Note that there is more than 1000 Line objects to process, thats why I thought Stream would be better.

Comment: please leave a comment for more information instead of downvoting.

Comment: First, use method references - it's somewhat cleaner. More importantly, just ask for some sort of "variable extractor" function as an input to your method. Then apply this function to your objects. You can then, fairly easily pass in the method reference to the getter as input to your summing method.

Comment: *Something* needs to know which variables (xx,yy,zz..) to sum up and either get the values in sequence to sum or perform the sum itself and return the result.. short of reflection and heuristics/annotations - which would result extra complex code - there is no way to make it 'more generic' and trying to do so is fighting the compile-time static typing.

Comment: It may be beneficial exploring the data-structure again, possibly changing how it is loaded into the object. Would  xx,yy,zz,.. not be better represented as an array or map?

Comment: Tell me about the method `fromJson`. Does it expect, say, a bean-style class?

Comment: @Gobernador "fromJson" loads the string of json into array of Line class objects. (deserializing string into java object)

Comment: Do you need to get all 30 sums at once?

Comment: By the way if `sumofTime` returns `long`, it would be better to use `mapToLong` instead of `mapToInt` to prevent possible overflow.

Comment: @Magnamag No, Mostly sum is needed for only individual attributes.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I'm new to java 8 concepts, its kinda hard to think in that perspective. it'll be great if you can provide some skeleton code for the solution that you suggest (using method referencing, etc).

Comment: I believe this post belongs to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/, not stackoverflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could pass a function into the sum method to get the value from each line that you want to sum:

```
public int sumLines(Function<Line, Integer> extractor){
    Line[] lines = ...
    return Arrays.stream(lines).map(extractor)
        .filter(Objects::nonNull).mapToInt(i -> i).sum();
}
....
int time = sumLines(Line::getTime);
```

This assumes that the function will return null if the attribute is not present, but you could also pass in a `Predicate` to filter with if that is not the case.

Comment: Nice. If you find it more readable (and less tautology-looking), the `mapToInt` arg can also be `Integer::intValue`.

Comment: getting null pointer exception. because some Line object have null values; the attributes in Line are Integer (default - null), not int (default - 0).

Answer (score 2):

What you're trying to do is partly a dynamic property extraction and partly a partially applied function, neither of which is particularly straightforward in Java. You'd be better off defining your `Line` class in a different way. I would use a `Map` to store the properties like so:

```
public class Line {
    Map<String, Integer> props;
    public Line() {
        // Initialize props
    }

    public boolean has(String prop) {
        return props.containsKey(prop);
    }

    public Integer get(String prop) {
        return props.get(prop);
    }

    public void set(String prop, Object value) {
        return props.put(prop, value);
    }
}
```

Now, when you're looking for the sum of a bunch of things, you can call

```
public int sumOf(Line[] lines, String prop) {
    return Arrays.stream(lines)
               .filter(l -> l.has(prop))
               .reduce(0, Integer::sum);
}
```

Comment: If the set of attributes is fixed (which it looks like it is), it's better to key the map by an enum than by `String`. That gives you type safety, and makes it much easier to know what attributes are available when you use the `Line`. As a bonus, an EnumMap is more efficient (in both memory and CPU) than HashMap or TreeMap.

Comment: While your answer is technically correct, I believe you're forgetting that the `Line[]` array is being deserialized from a JSON string, so the structure of the `Line` class should reflect this JSON input.

Comment: @yshavit could you please let me know how to do the custom deserialization to the Line class described above?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with gson, and anyway that would be too much for a comment. In sure there's plenty of documentation out there about it; if after reading that you still have a question, you should ask another question on SO.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than having a field per attribute, you could define an enum for the attributes, and then have a mapping from enum to int:

```
public enum LineAttribute {
    XX,
    YY,
    ZZ,
    ...
}

private final EnumMap<LineAttribute, Integer> attributes;

public Line() {
    attributes = new EnumMap<>(LineAttribute.class);
    // init all attributes to 0
    for (LineAttribute attr : LineAttribute.values()) {
        attributes.put(attr, 0);
    }
}
```

Then you can loop over each attribute, getting its values for the lines and summing those values.

```
private long sumOf(LineAttribute attr) {
    Line[] lines = gson.fromJson(jsonString, Line[].class);
    return Arrays.stream(lines)
            .filter(x -> x.has(attr))
            .mapToInt(x -> x.get(attr))
            .sum();
}
```

Comment: Line class also has two String attributes - name, and stamp. Although that is not used for calculations, they are associated (be together) with other integer attributes XX, YY, etc.

Comment: That's fine, just declare those as normal fields (as you did in your question). They won't be available in the `sumOf` method, but that's perfectly reasonable (desirable, even).

Comment: While your answer is technically correct, I believe you're forgetting that the `Line[]` array is being deserialized from a JSON string, so the structure of the `Line` class should reflect this JSON input.

Comment: It's unclear from the OP whether the object has to come from a _particular_ format of json, or whether it just needs to be json-serializable. In other words, it's unclear if the json format can be changed to suit the needs. Either way this answer should work; in the second case, you would need to write a custom ser/de, which I assume it's possible in gson (I know it is with jackson). But anyway, Alex's answer is better.